# MVC 3. Get EditorFor function to display a select box instead of a text box for the ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I created an app using MVC 3. I have one table that contains reference to another tables. Something like.

```
Clients              Reports
-------              ------------
ID                   ID
Name                 Description
                     Client_Id
```

Is there a way to make `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client_Id)` to display a select box with the names of the clients, instead of a text box to type the actual ID value?

Answer (score 2):

Make a strongly typed `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` View and put it in Views -> Shared -> EditorTemplates and call it YourReferencedModelList or something like that.  That view should render a drop down for you based on the passed in list of options:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, Model)
```

And finally, add the hint to your original model:

```
[UIHint("YourReferencedModelList")]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
```

You can find the full writeup here: http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/rendering-and-binding-drop-down-lists-using-asp-net-mvc-2-editorfor/